# Generating function with multiple variables with perfect square

Tags: quadratics

Consider trinomial  $x^2 + bx + c = 0$. When $b = 205$ and $c = -206$, then $x = 1$ and the function evaluates to a perfect square. My question is, how can I choose $b$ and $c$ and generate functions that are always a perfect square? I tried trial and error but couldn't find a mathematical way to solve the problem. Note that $a$ is always equal to $1$, we need to choose $b$ and $c$.

$$x^2 + 205x -206 = 0$$

Comment: "how can i choose b and c and generate functions that are always  a perfect squares?" - you can chose $b=c=0$.

Comment: i mean a general method similar to a perfect triangle

Comment: for  a perfect triangle  m > n > 0  , a=2mn , b = m^2 - n^2 and c is always perfect square

Comment: For quadratic functions just take $(x+b)^2=x^2+2bx+b^2$, which is always a square. For your example, $x^2+205x-206=(x-1)(x+206)$ is not always a square.

Comment: a is always a=1

Comment: $x^2+bx+c=\left(x+\frac b2\right)^2-b^2+c$

Comment: @HenryLee  , let me try that , sounds good so far

Comment: @HenryLee what is the relation between b and c , for example if b=132 , what is c ?